# android: no resource found ( manifest error)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

whenever a compile app this error comes .this problem is just in this app. i have develop other apps and their is no problem in that but whenever i compile this project this error starts coming.

```
gradle file is this:

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

     android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
      applicationId "cme.ws.com.ws.cme"
      minSdkVersion 8
      targetSdkVersion 22
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
     }
     buildTypes {
       release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),        'proguard-rules.pro'
             }
           }
      }

     dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
     }


error portion is this:
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

these are the errors.
gradle file is this
[image]

Comment: sometimes this happened after an android studio update

Comment: then what is the solution for this sir

Comment: Have you tried a full project-sync?

Comment: how can i sync  the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to res/values/styles.xml

add this code.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

"colorPrimary", "colorPrimaryDark","colorAccent"  are your app color attributes. In my case i have these values in my color.xml

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#1a2a3a</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#0e1720</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#1AB394</color>
```

Now clean and rebuild your project, problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **styles** folder under **values** under your **resources** folder.

> There exists this code, if not add it...and use AppCompatActivity.
>
> If exists check your Manifest file and add the theme at your application level

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

**Well try this**

> Go to **Build** > **Rebuild Project** in android Studio